# Enable debugging/logging on running EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, aws-cli

I forgot to add the following two options when creating my EMR cluster with the AWS CLI:

`--log-uri s3://mybucket/logs/ --enable-debugging`

Is there a way to add a log uri and enable debugging on a running cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do enable debugging to running cluster. 
The logs to s3 also needs to be enabled while you create cluster

By default, each cluster writes log files on the master node. These are written to the /mnt/var/log/ directory. You can access them by using SSH to connect to the master node

For more details please check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-debugging.html).